# How do i correct my responsive media query?

Tags: css, responsive

I am in the process of trying to correct some of the responsive issues on my WordPress site.

Before it looked like this in mobile view:

[image]

Then, i added the following code to my CSS in my child theme:

```html
@media only screen and (max-width: 768px) {
    .header-filter, .background-image {
  height: 85%;
  
 }
}
@media only screen and (max-width: 768px) {
     .hestia-title {
  height: auto;
  
 }
}
```

Now, it looks like this:

[image]

So, whilst the header image and title appear to have resized to fit the mobile screen, it has left a gap between that and the .blog-post div, showing the homepage image behind it (where the black gap is).

The blog post part of the site is already responsive as part of the theme i downloaded so i need to close the gap and bring the .blog-post up to meet the bottom of the header again, if possible.

Any ideas?

Thanks

Comment: Please create a [mcve] demonstrating your problem - we cannot help you fix it if you do not provide the code necessary to do so

Comment: HI, thank you for your reply. Apologies, I guess i thought that with the CSS i provided it would be clear as to what i am doing wrong. For example, use height:inherit; instead of height:auto; etc. I am new to coding so I'm not entirely sure what I need to provide here to reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

first of all check whether this line is in your file or not in  section.
if not added this line your file then firstly you add this line in

'< meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" >'

and check your responsive theme.

Comment: Hi, thanks for your reply. Would this be in the functions.php file of the parent theme?

Comment: i think this line added in index.php where write with <html> <head> </head> </html>in parent file.